# Python save images into the folder

Tags: python, image, api, instagram

I am using python-instagram API and I am displaying some images with searched tag!

Rather than displaying, I want to save those images so that it can be used for further analysis.

Is it possible? I am new to python and using API's.

Here is my code snippet which does this:

```
@route('/tag_search')
def tag_search(session): 
    access_token = session.get('access_token')
    content = "<h2>Tag Search</h2>"
    if not access_token:
        return 'Missing Access Token'
    try:
        api = client.InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token)
        tag_search, next_tag = api.tag_search(q="catband")
        tag_recent_media, next = api.tag_recent_media(tag_name=tag_search[0].name)
        photos = []
        for tag_media in tag_recent_media:
            photos.append('<img src="%s"/>' % tag_media.get_standard_resolution_url())
        content += ''.join(photos)
    except Exception, e:
        print e
```

Thanx in advance:)

Comment: Well, since you got image url, the logical thing would be to use said url to download the image.

Comment: Downloading files from an url is easy. See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python

Comment: @Puciek that was indeed a great idea, I will look into that.

Comment: @JayPatel then please post what you've done as an answer and accept it, so next person who will land in this question will be able to use your answer.

Comment: Yes @Puciek . I was able to achieve my goal. I used urllib
urllib.urlretrieve(image_url, name_image); Thanx for the help.:)

Comment: @JayPatel then please post it as an answer in that form just under comments so other can benefit from it!

Comment: @Puciek thanx for quick reply! Wrote the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some help from comments, and other resources, I found out that since I have URL of the image, I can use it to download!

The library which is used was "**urllib**"
I used a counter variable to save images in the same directory where the file is and in the form of 1.jpg, 2.jpg and so on and so forth.

Here is the modified code:

```
@route('/tag_search')
def tag_search(session): 
access_token = session.get('access_token')
content = "<h2>Tag Search</h2>"
if not access_token:
    return 'Missing Access Token'
try:
    api = client.InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token)
    tag_search, next_tag = api.tag_search(q="selfie")
    tag_recent_media, next = api.tag_recent_media(tag_name=tag_search[0].name)
    photos = []
    count = 0
    for tag_media in tag_recent_media:
        photos.append('<img src="%s"/>' % tag_media.get_standard_resolution_url())
        urllib.urlretrieve(tag_media.get_standard_resolution_url(), `count`+".jpg")
        count = count + 1
    content += ''.join(photos)
except Exception, e:
    print e
```

Hope this Helps:)

Comment: It would also be good to check it as the answer that helped you ;)

Comment: Yes, I will be only allowed after 15 hours.! You can upvote it. :)